# Angular application location service issue on mobile browsers

Tags: angular, mobile, safari, geolocation

Here is the scenario what I want to do.

I have an angular app which is getting the current device location after every 1 minute and checking that if the new coordinates are at least 1 mile away from the last location coordinates.

If its more than 1 mile then it will allow that coordinates in the array. this is done by `RxJs` Interval. There is another `RxJs` **Interval** which is calling the function to push the coordinates after every 5 minutes to the server. This function pushed the coordinates in batch and on the success of that call we remove the data from local array.

Everything works fine on PC but when we use this on the mobile device it works until the screen gets off. On mobile screen gets off every event stops working.

I want to know is there any solution for this type of scenario?

What you guys suggest?

Comment: Maybe this can help you out: https://davidwalsh.name/wake-lock-shim

Comment: @JacopoSciampi will this wake-lock-shim keep the mobile screen on?  I mean will it be on all the time which using this code. Can use force fully lock the screen ? If yes then application will keep running in the background?

Comment: I haven't tried it but at the end of the article it say how this trick works. Basically it "reprocude" a video over and over and the browser in the mobile phones catch that as "Ok, the user is playing a video, I wont turn off the screen".